# Is there a way to manually raise the PropertyChanged event of an EntityObject?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity, inotifypropertychanged

Hi I am trying to raise the PropertyChanged event of an EntityObject, I don't find a way to do it, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to decorate the property with an attribute and then call the ReportPropertyChanging and ReportPropertyChanged method like so:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(IsNullable = false)]
public byte Status
{
    get 
    {
        return _status;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_status != value)
        {
            ReportPropertyChanging("Status");
            _status = value;
            ReportPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrong. 
1) I wanted to workaround this ReportPropertyChanged, I wanted to raise the base class' event, the ReportPropertyChanged maybe eventually raises that event but it does more previous functionality too, when I said "manually raise" this is what I didn't want, I've just found the answer - very simple, take a look below.
2) The code shown above is generated by a tool and I am not gonna mess around with it.
3) I tagged my post with vb.net. Thank you for your response anyway.